# How to collect php metrics from mod_php?

Tags: apache, drupal, mod-php

As part of the performance testing of a Drupal web application and its infrastructure, I installed sensors on all hardwares and middleware bricks, but I dont know how to collect php metrics from mod_php (response time between apache and mod_php, ...).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You've not said what you are rying to acheive with this monitoring / testing. Mod_php (like all apache modules) is a shared library, hence there is no measurable response time *between* apache and mod_php.

Measuring request response time on the webserver is a good idea- it gives some insight into into infrastrcture problems but tells you very little about what performance the client is experiencing (at least it shouldn't). Hint: you should be logging and analysing %D. This is where RUM comes in - although this is hard to implement on a test environment.

It is possible to project data from PHP into Apache using apache_note() (e.g. for logging memory_get_peak_usage()).

Other things you should plumb in:

- an opcode cache manager
- SAR
- mod_status

...and capture the data.

Comment: thank you for your reponse, the application is a public portal, the numbrer of users will going to grow from 100 000 to 1 million user the purpos of our tests is to find when the Drupal application stops responds to our requirements in terms of user response time and wich brick is the responsible (hadrware, midlleware, application ..), the first diagnostic will help us to make changes efficiently (scale, ...) .

Comment: You might want to take a look at the URL on my profile page - follow the links to find some collected wisdom and research in performance management.